# ¿Cómo declarar una función con jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Tengo un formulario donde intento validar el RFC de un proveedor. Si el proveedor es una persona moral debe tener 12 caracteres, y si es una persona fisica debe tener 13.

uso la siguiente función para validar:

```
$(function ValidaRFC($rfc) {
        var strCorrecta;
        strCorrecta = $rfc;
        if ($("#TipoPersona :selected").text() == "Moral") {
            if ($($rfc).length == 12) {
                var valid = '^(([A-Z]|[a-z]){3})([0-9]{6})((([A-Z]|[a-z]|[0-9]){3}))';
            }
        }
        if ($("#TipoPersona :selected").text() == "Fisica") {
            if ($($rfc).length == 12) {
                var valid = '^(([A-Z]|[a-z]|\s){1})(([A-Z]|[a-z]){3})([0-9]{6})((([A-Z]|[a-z]|[0-9]){3}))';
            }

        }
        var validRfc = new RegExp(valid);
        var matchArray = strCorrecta.match(validRfc);
        if (matchArray == null) {
            alert('el rfc es incorrecto');

            return false;
        }
    });
```

pero no sucede nada, aunque ponga más de 12 o 13 caracteres, me deja guardar el proveedor.

en el input del rfc uso un `onblur = "ValidaRFC(this.value)"`

Comment: Relacionada: [Cómo validar un RFC de México y su digito verificador](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/31713/127)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema no está en las RegExp, sino en `$(function(){ ... })`: según la documentación de [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) la expresión `$(function(){ ... })` es equivalente:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ ... })
```

Lo que significa que no estás definiendo la función `ValidaRFC`, sino ejecutándola al cargarse el documento. Así, cuando se dispara el evento `blur`de la caja de texto, no se ejecuta tu función (porque está indefinida).

**Solución:** (Editado)

```
function ValidaRFC($rfc) { //Quité el '$(' de aquí...
    var strCorrecta;
    strCorrecta = $rfc;
    var longitudCorrecta = false;
    var valid;

    if ($("#TipoPersona :selected").text() == "Moral") {
        longitudCorrecta = (strCorrecta.length === 12);
        valid = '^(([A-Z]|[a-z]){3})([0-9]{6})((([A-Z]|[a-z]|[0-9]){3}))';          
    }
    if ($("#TipoPersona :selected").text() == "Fisica") {
        longitudCorrecta = (strCorrecta.length === 13);
        valid = '^(([A-Z]|[a-z]|\s){1})(([A-Z]|[a-z]){3})([0-9]{6})((([A-Z]|[a-z]|[0-9]){3}))';            
    }
    if(!longitudCorrecta){
        alert('el rfc es incorrecto');
        return false;
    }
    var validRfc = new RegExp(valid);
    var matchArray = strCorrecta.match(validRfc);
    if (matchArray == null) {
        alert('el rfc es incorrecto');

        return false;
    }
}; //...y el paréntesis de cierre aquí
```

Así, en el evento `blur` de la caja de texto se disparará la función como esperabas.

Comment: Gracias! funciona, pero al parecer no toma en cuenta el `($rfc).length == 12`, porque introduzco mas de 12 caracteres y se guarda. Por ejemplo un "mnvc123456mnvbcsd" y guarda, pero marca rfc es incorrecto si introduzco "1234nfmdj231msdkfs", creo que tiene que ver con la var valid, no sé si me explico.

Comment: (código editado): revisando con calma veo varios detalles, el principal es que estás declarando `valid` solo si la longitud es correcta (y si es incorrecta se crea un RegExp vacío). Lo otro es con `$($rfc).length` estas midiendo la longitud de un array jQuery que contiene una cadena, en lugar de la longitud de la cadena misma.

Comment: Muchas gracias :3 ya hice las pruebas y funciono correctamente!

Answer (score 1):

`$(document).ready(function(){ tu codigo })` debe ser reemplazada por `$(function() { tu codigo })`, asi jquery tomara las funciones declaradas,porque si no , te mostrara que la funcion no ha esta declarada