# ¿Existe actualmente alguna API para verificar existencia de RFCs en el SAT?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

Pues lo que dice la pregunta, yo actualmente estoy trabajando en una aplicación web empresarial, en la cual requerimos validar que el cliente tenga un RFC actual y que este valido o registrado en SAT.

Sé que hay validadores de CFDI pero no he encontrado alguna API de validación de existencia de RFCs.

¿Saben ustedes de alguna?.

Comment: saludos revisa esta url del SAT https://cfdisat.blob.core.windows.net/lco?restype=container&comp=list&prefix=l_RFC_2018_01_23 en ella esta una serie de archivos con los RFC validos, si notas al final de la url se tiene una fecha la cual puedes consultar en busca de una actualizacion, como nota te aviso que cada archivo tiene alrededor de 14 millones de RFC

Comment: también te comento que este tipo de preguntas no son bien recibidas en la comunidad, mas que nada por que la mayoría de las preguntas van orientadas a código como tal revisa el tour para ver que preguntas son bien recibidas aqui https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no trata de un problema de programación o desarrollo de software.

Comment: En [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/31713/c%C3%B3mo-validar-un-rfc-de-m%C3%A9xico-y-su-digito-verificador) puedes encontrar la información necesaria para poder saber que un RFC sea válido según las reglas del SAT. Me temo que no existe un servicio para saber si es válido ante el SAT, al menos que yo no lo conozca.

Comment: Muchas gracias jorge, creo que si me va servir.

Comment: ¿Entonces es esta pregunta un duplicado de la otra?

Comment: no se si considerarlo duplicado, ya que la otra pregunta valida que este en un formato valido pero eso no quiere decir que el SAT este usando el RFC realmente; pero tampoco considero que las etiquetas usadas sean las correctas, a fin de cuentas un WS puede estar en varios lenguajes de programación